# Cannot graph logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I am new to stack overflow, so please forgive me if any information needs to be added. Thanks for your patience.

I have tried several different techniques to plot some logistic regressions I'm working with, and although I can get my binomial data points to plot, everything I try gives me a straight line instead of a logistic curve. For the sake of brevity, I'll just ask about one technique [outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36685921/plot-logistic-regression-curve-in-r). The code I got from that, using the mtcars data, is as follows:

```
fit = glm(vs ~ hp, data=mtcars, family=binomial)
newdat <- data.frame(hp=seq(min(mtcars$hp), 
max(mtcars$hp),len=100))
newdat$vs = predict(fit, newdata=newdat, 
type="response")
plot(vs~hp, data=mtcars, col="red4")
lines(vs ~ hp, newdat, col="green4", lwd=2)
```

I swapped my data in for the above, word for word with the exception of the names of my initial dataset and the names of my binomial and continuous variables (both of which are integers just like the mtcars data), but rather than getting a result [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0ucJ.png), the line fitted to the plot is [completely straight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGWqV.png). I've played around with the mtcars data just to check, and it functions as intended, with a logistic curve.

Looking at the intermediate `newdat` data frame for my data, the only difference I can detect is that the values assigned to the binomial variable are larger, from 0.3 to 0.5, while the ones for the mtcars data are much smaller (circa 9.9e-01). I have no idea why this is or if it matters.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: A straight line might just mean that you don't get strong probabilities in either direction, within the range of your predictor. The central part of a logistic curve is pretty straight, it's only as you get towards 0 or 1 that it starts to curve. You could expand the range of x values you're predicting from, adding values much smaller or larger than your actual values, and see if you start to see a curve for extreme x values.

Comment: Thanks, @Marius. I do see from looking at my actual regression that the effect, while significant, is quite small, so I think this is the right answer. What I'm not sure of is how I can expand the range of x values that I'm predicting from - if I expended the values to, say, 600 (from around 400, where they are now), I wouldn't have any binomial response data. Would I need to simulate/extrapolate the data somehow?

Comment: Working off the example, you would just expand the range in `newdat` - you're only using it to see the predicted values so you don't need actual response data. So for the `mtcars` example, you would do something like `newdat <- data.frame(hp=seq(0, 500,len=100))` - adding some hp values outside the actual data range.

Comment: @Marius that worked like a charm. Thank you!