# Plotting logistic regression with multiple predictors?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, data-analysis

I ran the following logistic regression:

```
model<-glm(Choice~Cat+Dog+Rabbit+Cow,data=database,family=binomial(link="logit"))
summary(model)
```

Now, I'd like to visualize this regression with all four predictors. Thank you!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plot logistic regression curve in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36685921/plot-logistic-regression-curve-in-r)

Comment: Thanks! @user438383 but that answer only provides the code when there is one predictor. I'm not sure how to show multiple in one plot.

Comment: Hi Christina.. you can only visualize one predictor or at most 2 at a time. You can improve the question by being a bit more specific, like how you want to visualize the data, otherwise this might be a bit too broad.

Comment: One package you can try is ggeffect, https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/practical_logisticmixedmodel.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a multivariate regression, so you need to vary one variable and hold others constant, this is called marginal effect. You can code it from scratch to visualize it, and I think there are some useful packages like [ggeffects](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/index.html) or [sjplot](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sjPlot/vignettes/plot_marginal_effects.html). Before I use an example dataset and plot the effects:

```
library(ggeffects)
dat = iris
dat$Species = as.numeric(dat$Species=="versicolor")
mdl = glm(Species ~ .,data=dat,family="binomial")

summary(mdl)

Call:
glm(formula = Species ~ ., family = "binomial", data = dat)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.1280  -0.7668  -0.3818   0.7866   2.1202  

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)    7.3785     2.4993   2.952 0.003155 ** 
Sepal.Length  -0.2454     0.6496  -0.378 0.705634    
Sepal.Width   -2.7966     0.7835  -3.569 0.000358 ***
Petal.Length   1.3136     0.6838   1.921 0.054713 .  
Petal.Width   -2.7783     1.1731  -2.368 0.017868 *
```

To visualize one:

```
plot(ggpredict(mdl,"Petal.Width"))
```

[image]

To make these plots for all variables:

```
library(patchwork)

plts = lapply(names(coefficients(mdl))[-1],function(i){
       return(plot(ggpredict(mdl,i)))
       })

wrap_plots(plts)
```

[image]

As mentioned before, those plots are obtained via the marginal effects, that is keeping others at their mean values. You can also explore it by keep another variable at different value, for example:

```
plot(ggpredict(mdl,c("Petal.Width","Petal.Length")))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! @StupidWolf amazing :)... Can you please explain briefly how to interpret the plots for each of the variables?

Comment: On the y-axis of each is plot is the probability of being 1 or the level you coded to be the non-reference. The x-axis would be the predictor, and you see if you hold other variables constant, how the probability of being 1 changes

Comment: For example petal.width, if you have a sample that has low petal.width, the model would predict it to be 0, assuming your other variables are around the mean value. If you have some information about petal length, you can incorporate it and this is the last plot

Comment: If you have a sample that has low petal.length, for example around 1.99 (red line), and it has low petal.width, then probability of this sample being one is around 0.5

Comment: thank you so much!! @StupidWolf and what does the shaded area represent?

Comment: the shaded area is the 95% confidence interval of the prediction

Comment: Amazing!!! this was great. Last question, are the other variables removed when plotting each predictor on its own? or are they held at constant?

Comment: they are held at constant...

Comment: This answer is so great @StupidWolf. However, in my model are some dummy variables (binary indicators). And using library(patchwork)

plts = lapply(names(coefficients(mdl))[-1],function(i){
       return(plot(ggpredict(mdl,i)))
       })

wrap_plots(plts) 

I receive errors as in: `dummy1yes` was not found in model terms. Maybe misspelled?
 Error in names(x) <- value : 
'names' attribute [7] must be the same length as the vector [6]

Any idea how to fix this?